# Deleted comment

Tags: support, answers, comments

I normally wouldn't worry about a deleted comment, but I got a reply to my comment on [this question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/3842/133) that seems to suggest I should post it as an answer instead (the only reason I didn't in the first place is I hadn't expected to write so much, and figured it would be insufficient as an answer and more appropriate as a comment).

However, when I clicked my inbox notification to read the full response (and convert my comment to an answer), not only had the response been deleted, but my comment had as well!

Could a mod provide the content of my comment, so I can repost it as an answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your comment was:

> They would both be correct here. The main difference is that *tall* always refers to the height of something (its size), whereas *high* (while used this way for structures), can be (and often is) used to describe the elevation of something.